# I want to delete all the 16 from the following array using numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

[image]
I want to delete all the 16 from the following array using numpy

Comment: The array is in the image attached as "enter image description here"

Comment: what have you tried? can you add any code examples that arent working?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ - Please show what you tried and what failed. For more information about why I downvoted, see the link :)

Comment: Post Image  as a code is not best way to ask question. Add code and for better clarity add Image too if needed.

Comment: Share your code

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

As all the comments state, please add code and, if needs be, add an image.

When you say "delete all the 16", do you mean replace them with other values or just select a sub-array without the 16?

It seems that the 16 are always placed at the end of each line, hence you could do

```
img # array containing the 16, of shape (X,Y,4)
img_no16 = img[:,:,:3]  # this gets you rid of the last column and returns an array of shape (X,Y,3)
```

If, however, you'd like to replace all the `16` in the array you have two options

1. If they are always placed at the end of each line, you can do something similar to above
   `img[:,:,:3] = 0 # or any other number`
2. If you don't know where the 16 are and just want to replace them all by, say, -1, you can do 
   `img[np.where(img == 16)] = -1`